# How to disable a viewcell but allow clicks on a button within it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button in a view cell that's in a table view.

The cell/row flashes when I press on it but if I set the row to `IsEnabled = false`, then I can't click on the button.

Is there a way around this? Could I put the button outside the table and still have it scroll with the table?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the selection mode of the ListView to "none"? If you do that it should still respond to taps but will not be highlighted.